# OpenMP: parallelizing (Approximation) Code makes it not only faster, but more accurate. Why?

Tags: c, algorithm, parallel-processing, openmp

i have parallelized a simple code for calculating numerically an integral of a function. I use it with the function `y=2*sqrt(1-x^2)` from -1 to 1. This integral is equal to Pi.

The Algorithm is the simplest way to calc an integral, I guess everyone learned it in school. I "draw" rectangles of a small size under the function and calculate their area.

The sequential algorithm is:

```
double calc_integral_seq(int left_bound, int right_bound){
  int i;
  double x, sum=0.0;
  double step = 1.0/ (double) STEPS;

  for(i=left_bound*STEPS; i<right_bound*STEPS; i++){
        x = (i+0.5)*step;
        sum += f(x);
  }
return sum*step;
}
```

Now, when I parallelize this code (for instance by only using the for-loop construct `#pragma omp parallel for private(x) reduction(+:sum)`) the algorithm is way faster for huge sizes of `STEPS`.

But it is also more accurate! How can that be? This is a deterministic algorithm, it should calculate the exact same value or am I wrong? How can this be explained?

Comment: *This is a deterministic algorithm*  In practice it is better to think of parallelised algorithms which depend on floating-point arithmetic as only approximately deterministic, since they generally surrender control over the order of operations, and as we all know f-p arithmetic is not properly associative.  As Zulan's answer explains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a rounding issue. Whenever you add a very small to a very large number, there is a rounding error, because the small change cannot be accurately described by the floating point number with a large exponent. The rounding error per addition increases with increasing `sum` value.

By doing the computation in parallel, the local `sum` does not grow as large as it does for the serial loop. So locally, there is less rounding error. Also the summation towards the global `sum`, the local results are much closer together, so there is less rounding.

General algorithms to avoid floating point rounding errors are [Kahan summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm) or [pairwise summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_summation).